# Rufus-Scheduler issue for cron jobs in linode ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, linode, rufus-scheduler

My initializers/task_scheduler.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

scheduler.cron '*/5 * * * *' do
  Project.cron_for_report
end
```

My Issue is I am getting 12 mails of report every 5 minutes. I should get only 1 mail every 5 minute. Should I use something like mutex?? Please give some example code.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It does not sound like a rufus-scheduler issue, it sounds like you are running 12 Rails processes, but you don't tell what you're running Rails on (Unicorn, Passenger, ... ?).

Since you're running on Ubuntu, you are free to use crond. Why don't you have a look at https://github.com/javan/whenever ? It'll let you leverage crond's strength from your Rails application.

Rufus-scheduler is fun, but if you simply start it each time Rails starts, you'll end up with a rufus-scheduler instance for each Rails process, unless you place some logic in the initializer to avoid such a situation (lock files, etc). And your logic has to be smart enough to avoid locks pointing on dead schedulers preventing starting new, needed, schedulers, etc.

Since you deploy on Linode/Ubuntu, you're free to consider other alternatives like Whenever.

Sorry, no example code, I don't want you to become a copy-paste programmer.

Comment: That was a mistake. The current issue is job is executed 4 times. my rails app contains 4 unicorn workers.Perhaps this causes 4 schedulers to be created. How to make it as 1 scheduler ?